# Typescript vscode refactoring: Move class from file to another (existent) file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, refactoring

When reorganizing a project with many classes, a frequent need is to move some class to another existent file.

I have searched the vscode features and extesions and I haven't been able to find some refactoring that does that.

Anyone knows of such a possiblitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now offically supported in [v1.82](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_82#_move-to-file-refactoring)

Comment: Does it work with TS types? It only shows me "Move to a new file..." in that context window.

Comment: @gabrielhpugliese I think you need **Typescript v5.2.2** \ & restart vscode \ > VS Code now ships with TypeScript 5.2.2. \ (& also, if you changed the workspace Typescript version before, then `ctrl+shift+p` > `TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version...`, maybe)

Comment: Is there a "refactor preview" option for move to a file?

Comment: @gabrielhpugliese Just found that some extensions may disable that ability (eg: `Typescript React hooks Tools` at current stage.)

Answer (score 3):

You have refactoring features in VC Code out of the box.

Here is the DOC: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-refactoring

Excerpt from documentation:

> To see the available TypeScript refactorings, put your cursor on a region of your source code and either right-click to bring up the editor context menu and select Refactor or press `Ctrl+Shift+R` directly.

> **Move to new file** - Move one or more classes, functions, constants, or interfaces in the top-level scope of the file to a new file. The new file's name is inferred from the selected symbol's name.

[image]

Comment: @Expermienter thanks but what I was looking for is moving the class to an *existing* file. I will edit the question to make it clearer